# ValidationSummary does not display error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I cannot get a custom error to appear in my ValidationSummary. (Property-level errors display correctly, as expected.)

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(ContactViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            Mail mail = new Mail
            {
                ToAddress = "user@example.com",
                Subject = model.Subject,
                Body = model.Message
            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Email))
                mail.FromAddress = model.Email;

            await mail.SendAsync();

            return View("ContactConfirm");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I can step through my code and see that the line `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex);` is executed, and there is a valid error, but the markup does not render any error message.

NOTE: While nothing is visible on the page, the underlying markup for the validation summary is as follows:

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors text-danger">
    <ul>
        <li style="display:none"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why my error is not displayed?

Comment: Try using  `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

Comment: @AdnanNiloy: No, that is to show property-level errors, which I don't want displayed in the summary. This is not a property-level error as you can see by my setting the key to `string.Empty`. Note that I did try it just to confirm--it does not help.

Comment: Oops! My bad! I see @sleeyuen has gave you the solution. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex);
}
```

Since one of the overloads accepted an `Exception`, I assumed the text would be correctly extracted from the exception that I provided. But it isn't.

Making the following change causes the error to be displayed correctly in the validation summary.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I am getting same error. tried same method but it's not helping.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the first parameter to false:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

It specifies whether to exclude property errors.

Comment: No, I do not. That would cause any property-level errors to display in the summary. This is not a property-level error, as evidenced by the fact that I used `string.Empty` as my key.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! In that case, perhaps change `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex);` to use `ex.Message`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and it worked! Was just posting that result as your comment came in.

Comment: I see that - at least you figured it out. Weird, because AddModelState does indeed accept Exception as one of its overloads.

Comment: Yes, I've submitted a potential bug to a Microsoft contact.

Comment: Apparently this behaviour affects MVC3 through 5 - not sure about 6.